# Why can't eshell/echo print dashes?

Tags: eshell

For some reason it appears eshell/echo can't handle dashes:

```
$ echo "aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
$ echo "============="
=============
$ echo "-------------"
$
```

Is this expected behavior? I assume it's interpreting the dashes as flags and the quote isn't helping inhibit that. Should I be escaping it a different way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `--` to tell `eshell` not to interpret arguments that follow as command-line switches. This is the standard way of passing an argument (such as a file name) starting with a dash to GNU tools.

In summary: try

```
echo -- "-------------"
```

or just

```
echo -- -------------
```

(as far as I can tell all arguments are interpreted as strings).

There are two issues (I would even say *bugs* here):

- `eshell--process-args` uses `"^-\\(-\\)?\\(.*\\)"` to match switches, i.e. anything starting with one or two dashes is treated as a switch and removed from the list of arguments. If we disallow switches starting with three dashes and use `"^-\\(-\\)?\\([^-].*\\)"`, `echo ---` works as expected.
- `eshell--process-option` has a bug that prevents it from printing an error message when an unrecognized switch is passed to an `eshell` command without an "external" equivalent.

See the code block below for the fixed version. (Note that `(error ...)` is outside `(when extcmd ...)`.

```lisp
(defun eshell--process-option (name switch kind ai options opt-vals)
  "For NAME, process SWITCH (of type KIND), from args at index AI.
    The SWITCH will be looked up in the set of OPTIONS.

    SWITCH should be either a string or character.  KIND should be the
    integer 0 if it's a character, or 1 if it's a string.

    The SWITCH is then be matched against OPTIONS.  If no matching handler
    is found, and an :external command is defined (and available), it will
    be called; otherwise, an error will be triggered to say that the
    switch is unrecognized."
  (let* ((opts options)
         found)
    (while opts
      (if (and (listp (car opts))
               (nth kind (car opts))
               (equal switch (nth kind (car opts))))
          (progn
            (eshell--set-option name ai (car opts) options opt-vals)
            (setq found t opts nil))
        (setq opts (cdr opts))))
    (unless found
      (let ((extcmd (memq ':external options)))
        (when extcmd
          (setq extcmd (eshell-search-path (cadr extcmd)))
          (if extcmd
              (throw 'eshell-ext-command extcmd)))
        (error (if (characterp switch) "%s: unrecognized option -%c"
                 "%s: unrecognized option --%s")
               name switch)))))
```

PS: I'm using `GNU Emacs 24.5.1`.

Comment: This isn't really satisfactory as `echo "---"` in zsh does the right thing.

Comment: @wasamasa: Well, that's what `eshell` does in Emacs 24.5.1. I think I know why; please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is already better, though I find it still concerning "---" is interpreted as invalid option and "--" is accepted silently.